# Plot not shown in viewer when using plotly

Tags: r, ggplotly

Attempting to run some tutorial code as a first time user of plotly. However, the plot does not appear in the Viewer pane and the following message is produced (in Viewer):

**/session/viewhtml36b8729177dc/index.html?viewer_pane=1&capabilities=1&host=http%3A%2F%... not found**

Code used

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(plotly)

recent_grads <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/college-majors/recent-grads.csv")

majors_processed <- recent_grads %>%
  arrange(desc(Median)) %>%
  mutate(Major = str_to_title(Major),
         Major = fct_reorder(Major, Median))

g <- majors_processed %>%
  mutate(Major_category = fct_lump(Major_category, 4)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(ShareWomen, Median, color = Major_category, size = Sample_size, label = Major)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = 1), method = "lm") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = percent_format()) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar_format()) +
  expand_limits(y = 0)

ggplotly(g)
```

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)
plotly_4.9.2.1
RStudio 1.3.1073
```

Any support on this will be very appreciated.

Comment: you could try this: `x11() ggplotly(g)` x11() opens a windows graphic console which is more powerful than the built in viewer

Comment: Thanks. No luck with this, returns Error: unexpected symbol in "x11() ggplotly". I have attempted a few variations too.

Comment: open in an explorer (third icon top left in the viewer), the viewer sometime does not work on some computers. Happens to me

Comment: @denis - thanks. Already tried this. Unfortunately it does not solve the issue.

Comment: This code works fine for me.  Perhaps you need to re-install R and R-Studio.  I had a similar issue until I upgraded RStudio.

Comment: @YBS - Thanks. An update to R 4.0.2 from 4.0.0 seems to have solved the issue. Thanks all for the support.