# Pie-Donut Chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, donut-chart

I would like to create a Pie-Donut chart like the next one:

[image]

For this I am using the next code:

```r
PieDonut(df1, aes(Species, Costs, count=Entries),
         ratioByGroup = F, explode = 1, r0 = 0.5, r1 = 0.7)
```

But I am not getting the two different (independent) charts. This is the result:
[image]

As you can see the ratios of both groups are not the same:
The first donut should be according to the variable "Costs" and the second "Entries"

This is the data I am using:

```r
structure(list(Species = c("Cercopagis pengoi", "Dreissena polymorpha"
), Costs = c(0.27, 33.27), Entries = c(7L, 5L), fraction = c(0.00805008944543828, 
0.991949910554562), ymax = c(0.00805008944543828, 1), ymin = c(0, 
0.00805008944543828)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would really appreciate some help,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is this function from? https://cardiomoon.github.io/webr/reference/PieDonut.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I got a `plotly` option. You can create two pies with plotly with one for the hole and one for the outer circle using two `add_pie`. You can use the following code:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

plot_ly(df1) %>%
  add_pie(labels = ~`Species`, values = ~`Costs`, 
          type = 'pie', hole = 0.7, sort = F,
          marker = list(line = list(width = 2))) %>%
  add_pie(df1, labels = ~`Species`, values = ~`Entries`, 
          domain = list(
            x = c(0.15, 0.85),
            y = c(0.15, 0.85)),
          sort = F) %>%
  layout(title = "Chart", 
         legend = list(title = list(text = "Species")))
```

Output:

[image]

### Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Species = c("Cercopagis pengoi", "Dreissena polymorpha" ), Costs = c(0.27, 33.27), Entries = c(7L, 5L), fraction = c(0.00805008944543828,  0.991949910554562), ymax = c(0.00805008944543828, 1), ymin = c(0,  0.00805008944543828)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: thanks so much for your fast reply. I am sorry for bothering you again, but I am getting the next error message: /session/viewhtml9834373811d5/index.html?viewer_pane=1&capabilities=1&host=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A18550 not found on "viewer" @Quinten

Comment: @IsmaSotoAlmena, I added some extra code and the data. Maybe you should reinstall R and Rstudio like in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720935/plot-not-shown-in-viewer-when-using-plotly.